# What can I substitute for git-checkout-index under Git for Windows?

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I use git under Microsoft Windows.

Recently, my workplace stopped using Cygwin and substituted Git for Windows.  For the most part, this has been fine, but my legacy `pre-commit` hook uses `git-checkout-index` and that doesn't seem to be part of Git for Windows.

Is there some way for me to work around that by substituting a script definition for `git-checkout-index` based on git commands that *do* exist in Git for Windows?

Comment: are you saying the command [git checkout-index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout-index) does not work in [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/)? As I see it it should work just out of the box. Or is you pre-commit hook not working anymore?

Comment: Thank you for your interest, @caramba.  Both statements are actually true, but this question is about the fact that the git-checkout-index command does not seem to *exist* in Git for Windows.

Comment: are you typing `git-checkout-index` or `git checkout-index`?

Comment: ```git-checkout-index```.  When I replace it with ```git checkout-index``` the error disappears.  Annoying, because I thought that the two calls should be interchangeable.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`git checkout-index` works.  Thank you to caramba for answering this in the comments on the question.